# Destructuring nested structs in Rust

Tags: rust

Is it possible to destructure structs in Rust when they are nested?

```
struct S2 {
    field1: i64,
    field2: i64,
}

struct S1 {
    field1: String,
    field2: S2,
}

let s1 = S1 {
    field1: String::from("hello"),
    field2: S2 {
        field1: -1,
        field2: 0,
    }
}

let S1 {
    field1,
    S2 {
        field1: field1_s2,
        ..
    }
} = s1;
```

I would assume the answer is "no" - but just in case there is a way to do something similar, or perhaps my syntax is wrong.

Comment: Nice question and [the Rust docs ask this question too](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/structs.html): "Add a function `rect_area` which calculates the area of a `Rectangle` (try using nested destructuring)." (Where `Rectangle`contains two `Point` fields)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible, but you need to specify the field name:

```rust
let S1 {
    field1,
    field2: S2 {
        field1: field1_s2, ..
    },
} = s1;
```